# Right click acting like the left click

Tags: mouse, touchpad, tap-to-click

After updating my Ubuntu to version 22.04, I noticed that the right-click is behaving like the left-click. For example, when I try to open the context menu by right-clicking on a file, it instead opens the file itself and the same if I click left click.

Could anyone please provide some help?

Thanks in advance.